# how can i update cell value when i pop to tableview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my uinavigation controller based application when i click to tableview cell it push me a new table view where i can choose values, i save them in to shared preferences and on pop i need to have that value in the cell where i have clicked, but i do not know where to call the     `[myTableView ReloadData];` procedure.
I have the value there only when i scroll the table view.I m sure it can be made simply but i just do not find out how.

can you help me?

thanks

pushing:

```
       [myTableView reloadData];

        Choose *choose = [[Choose alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:choose animated:YES];
        choose.navigationItem.title = @"Ucty";
        choose.myArray = rootArray;

        [choose release];

        [myTableView reloadData];
```

poping:

```
    [zKtorehoUctu setObject:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*5+2] forKey:@"zUctu"];

    [zKtorehoUctu synchronize];  

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it, but this method should not be used the secondviewcontroller inherit the pointer of firstviewcontroller's tableview, and then when i choose the value i just call reloadData.

It is not good way to solve it but it works.

hope my answer or Deepak 's answer hwlp to solve You this kind of problem

bye

Answer (score 1):

do it in `-viewWillAppear:`. That should do it.

Comment: it does not call the method when is poped into the view :( i tested it on debug mode

Comment: It should be called . Can you provide some relevant code related to pushing/popping of the second view controller?